# How to fix jaws screen reader accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, angular, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

In my web page i set the screen reader automatically read some content. When screen reader read last content(percentage) then after press down arrow key then focus on next element(footer) but screen reader move to first element(header).
I need to focus on next element instead of first element. For this I am using angular 11.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div>
    <span role="alert">
      <span> Preparing environment...</span>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
<span  [attr.aria-label]="Your environment ready in {{minutes}} minutes {{second}} seconds">
    <span aria-hidden="true">
      <span>Your environment ready in </span>
      <countdown *ngIf="!min" [config]="minutes" (event)="handleCountDown($event)"></countdown>
      <span> {{ minutes }}</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div class="progress" >
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      {{ percentage }} %
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>

header code

<div role="banner" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-0 headerBg" role="banner">
    <img class="logo" aria-label="company logo" src="./logo.jpg" />
</div>


footer code
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo" aria-label="footer" class="footerBottom">
  <div class="row">
      <p class="mb-0">
       <span> footer...</span> 
      </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You will have to show your code, otherwise how will we know what elements are being talked about here.

Comment: Okay let me post

Comment: Your last p tag is the one not being read out right? It does not have a closing `</p>` . Try adding that after the `</span>`

Comment: No it's not p tag issue.
Here I forgot to close p tag

Comment: Ok. Maybe try putting content directly in `p` for once and remove your `span`. `span` does not mean anything semantically. BTW, it works on my NVDA.

Comment: Yes, In NVDA  working fine but In JAWS  not working.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Using the down arrow, whether NVDA or JAWS, will move to the next element in the DOM.  Can you post the code of the rendered page?  Your sample above has comments "header code", "footer code", as well as angular stuff.  When the page is loaded, go to the browser inspector and copy/paste what you see there.